# Nodejs how to create directories containing files with the same name

Tags: node.js

I'm using [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) node package to create the folders and files but the files are not in the correct path they end up on the same level as the folders, I need each file to be contained within the newly created folder.

```
fs.mkdirs(filenames[i], function (err) {

  if (!err){
    fs.writeFile( './'+filenames[i]+'.html', 'hello world' , function( error ){
      console.log(error);

    });
  }

});
```

Comment: What is the actual name you want for the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be what you want:

```
fs.mkdirs(filenames[i], function (err) {

  if (!err){
    fs.writeFile(filenames[i]+'/'+filenames[i]+'.html', 'hello world' , function( error ){
      console.log(error);

    });
  }

});
```